# How to get the 1st number and the 2nd number in a string?

Tags: vb.net

The string is "What is 8 multiplied by 2?"

How can I get the first 1st number which is "8" and the second number which is "2"?
What I want is to get the first number and use the mathematical operation asked to the second number.

```
Dim str As String = Label1.Text
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(str)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
        Label2.Text = Mid(str, i, 1)
    End If
Next
```

I tried using this but I only get the 2nd number which is "2"

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet as a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you already tried? If you need more information, see [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Questions of the form "I want to do X, tell me how" are off-topic at SO. This is a place to ask questions of the form "I want to do X, this is how I'm trying to do X, this is what happens when I try it, tell me what's wrong". If you want to manipulate strings then you need to do some research on string manipulation. You need to try to learn first, not just as us to tell you how or do it for you.

Comment: sorry about that, I already included my code. I am really not that good at coding yet

Comment: You want to write either a string parser or a regular expression (regex).  The string parser is theoretically better, the regex is shorter. On the other hand the popular saying for regex is “You have a problem and decided to use regex to solve it, now you have two problems”.  But here’s a possible solution \D+(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim str As String = "What is 8666 multiplied by 2444"
    Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)

    For Each word As String In str.Split(" ")
        If IsNumeric(word) Then
            numbers .Add(CInt(word))
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox("first:" & numbers (0) & ",second:" & numbers (1))
```

Comment: Works only for 1 character numbers.

Comment: That’s much better, but if you are going to iterate over the string, decimal.tryparse and a list of decimals would be better (integer.tryparse if the OP is only dealing with integers).